# how to display mapview in tableview cell with sections?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, mapkit

I have one tableview with sections.First section there are 4 rows with label in it.
In second and third section i have custom button.In fourth section i want to display
mapview to display current location of user.does anyone have any idea how can i do it.
Any tutorials or sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom `UITableViewCell` ([info](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18)) and add an `MKMapView` to it. Then simply configure your map view and implement the `MKMapView` [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKMapViewDelegate) to respond to changes.

Comment: ]mapView=[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:frame22];
   mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;
   CLLocationCoordinate2D location = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
   MKCoordinateSpan span;
            
   MKCoordinateRegion region;
   
   location.latitude  = [[aVolunteer latitude] floatValue];
   location.longitude = [[aVolunteer longitude] floatValue];
   mapView.scrollEnabled=YES;
   span.latitudeDelta = 0.05;
   span.longitudeDelta = 0.05;

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to set delegate & add mapView in the contentView of cell .

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

 MKMapView *mapView; 
 NSString *locationStr; 
 MKAnnotationView *annotationView;


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if(indexPath.section ==3)
    {
          Initialize & alloc memory to Object of MKMapView
          [cell.contentView addSubView:mapView]; //Add it to cells contentView
}
return cell;
   }
```

To drop Annotation on MapView use this Delegate MEthod:

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

// Use this method for placing custom Annotation in MapView

 }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I have solved the problem by inserting following code:mapView=[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:frame22];
   mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;
   CLLocationCoordinate2D location = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
   MKCoordinateSpan span;
            
   MKCoordinateRegion region;
   
   location.latitude  = [[aVolunteer latitude] floatValue];
   location.longitude = [[aVolunteer longitude] floatValue];
   mapView.scrollEnabled=YES;
   span.latitudeDelta = 0.05;
   span.longitudeDelta = 0.05;

Comment: Have you done it with mapView in the contentView of cell or any other way ??Since you were supposed to to it in UITableView... ;)

Comment: i have declared subview like this UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0,   300, 45)];
then in 4th section
case 3:
   
subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[subView insertSubview:[self loadMap] atIndex:0];
cell1.backgroundView = subView;
[subView release];
and then written the code above comment in loadmap function